# How to calculate the number of remaining uses URLFetch?

Tags: google-apps-script

I use "URLFetch" in my Google Adwords Scripts every day. And I want to know how many requests I have left for the day. Does anyone know how to do this means Google Scripts?

Comment: You can check in this [page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) the list of quotas for the Google Services under the Apps Script.
The URL Fetch calls has a limit of `20,000 / day` for every consumer/gmail. Just check the page to see the other [current limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) of URL Fetch data receives and others.

Comment: Yep, but I want to use some counter variable, which shows me URLFetch balance at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to look at this page to find out more https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app:

```js
function onOpen() {

// The code below logs the HTML code of the Google home page.
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/");
 Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  
}
```

Comment: Super, but this is just the return. I want to get access to Google Adwords Scripts increment under the quota